# How does ship agility work with entering warp?

Tags: eve-online

How does ship agility affect the time it takes to get to warp speed for a ship in EVE? Is higher better or lower better and are there other factors to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ships agility depends on your ships mass. A higher agility value means faster alignment.

The lower your mass, the faster you can align to your warp target and warp away. That is why Frigates and Shuttles can get to warp way faster than a capital or a freighter.

There are also certain skills and modules that help you to get to warp faster, e.g.:

- Spaceship Command
- Evasive Maneuvering

Example Mods:

- Inertia Stabilizers
- Nanofiber Internal Structure

Comment: So mass should be lower and agility value (the wing icon on the fitting screen) should be higher for fastest align times?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you want for a fast align time.